How do I add access to Windows API to my WPF project?
I've created a brand-new WPF project under .NET 8.0, but when adding
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;

I get an error saying CS0234: The type or namespace 'Windows' name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?).
I've tried multiple things from answers on stackoverflow but none of them have worked :

Adding the nuget package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts
Adding the Windows .NET SDK : There is no .NET tab in the window to add a dependency
Adding the it directly in the csproj and doing dotnet restore : hangs.


Are you targeting Windows platform specifically?

"You can add the Windows Runtime by opening the shortcut menu for the project node, choosing Unload Project, adding the following snippet, and re-opening the project (on the project node choose Reload Project): <PropertyGroup><TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion></PropertyGroup>" This goes into the main <PropertyGroup>.

This question is similar to: Which DLL has the Windows.Devices.Gelocation namespace?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Windows.Devices.Bluetooth is a UWP name space. It works when you start with a "UWP project".
